# How to add nodes continuously in graph databases using gremlin-python

Tags: python, graph-databases, gremlin

I am a week old in gremlin and graph databases. My question is: Is there a way to add nodes to the graph database using gremlin-python ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gremlin-python library gives you full access to the Gremlin language which includes mutating steps like `addV()` for adding vertices and `addE()` for adding edges...so, sure, just use Gremlin to add vertices/edges in python as you would with any other language that Gremlin supports.

Comment: @stephenmallete, I am fetching data from RDBMS and want to construct graph out of it. Is this the right way of doing it ?

Comment: sure. nothing wrong with that. if your graph is really large and time is a factor you might wish to use some form of bulk loading capability, but then you'd typically be looking at the tools provided by the specific graph database you've chosen or some form of custom `VertexProgram` for data loading.